# How to search files from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a list

```
fileslist=[1.jpg,2.xml,3.png]
```

I want to search files in list in current working directory
I have tried

```
listingdir=os.getcwd()
for rootpath,directories,files in os.walk(listingdir):
    for file in fileslist:
        if file in files:
            print("file:{} found".format(file))
```

I also tried

```
list=(set(files).intersection(fileslist))
```

but not worked because of not only one type extentions in files 
when I used set it creates a list like following and i don't get the results

```
f=set(files)
print(f)
#result is
[[1.jpg,2.jpg,....],[1.png,2.png,...],[1.xml,2.xml,.......]]
```

Comment: Please show your **real** data. It is not possible for your last snippet of code to print result like that.

Comment: Read up on [`os.path.exists(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=exist#os.path.exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to search through the current dir, you can do something like:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f)]

fileslist = ['1.jpg','2.xml','3.png']
list = (set(files).intersection(fileslist))
```

Output:

```
{'1.png'}  # it wont always be this, just an example.
```

Comment: `os.listdir(...)` `path` argument is not necessary, if you are listing the files in the current working directory. So you may just use `os.listdir()` instead of `os.listdir('.')`

Comment: That's correct. It would consider the default value for path `('.')`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `os.path.isfile(...)`. It will check if a certain file exists. It may accept a full path or a filename only (then it will check if the file exists in the current working directory).

```
import os.path
fileslist=['1.jpg','2.xml','3.png'] # no, it won't work without the quotes! 
for f in fileslist:
    if os.path.isfile(f):
         print("file:{} found".format(f))
```